# Find the angle between the main diagonal of a cube and a skew diagonal of a face of the cube

Tags: geometry

I was told it was $90$ degrees, but then others say it is about $35.26$ degrees. Now I am unsure which one it is.

[image]

Comment: I have a quick question. What is the angle between the main diagonal of the cube and the other diagonal on the bottom face of the cube? By other diagonal, I mean the one that it is not skew too.?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what you mean by the skew diagonal.

Consider the cube with corners at $(x,y,z)$ where each element is either zero or one.

In particular, one diagonal is $0=(0,0,0)$ to $u=(1,1,1)$.

Now it depends on what you mean by a "skew diagonal."

If $0$ to $v=(1,1,0)$ is the other diagonal you are looking form, then the cosine of the angle is $$\frac{u\cdot v}{|u||v|}=\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}\sqrt{2}}$$

The inverse cosine of that value is approximately $35.26$ degrees.

On the other hand, if you mean a skew diagonal such as the diagonal from $(1,0,0)$ and $(0,1,0)$, then that vector of that diagonal is $w=(-1,1,0)$, and $u\cdot w=0$ so the two angles are perpendicular.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by the skew diagonal, though. Editing to reflect that...

Comment: I will post a picture. Give me just a minute.

Comment: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/856/photojpp.jpg/

Comment: Check the picture out I put. The darker lines are what I am trying to find the angle of.

Comment: Yes, that is the latter situation - the 90 degree situation. You can see it directly through symmetry that it has to be 90 degrees I think.

Comment: Okay thanks. I am trying to figure the reasoning out now. The other case seemed easier to reason out.

Answer (score 2):

Take your cube

$\hspace{100pt}$[image: single cube]

and make three more copies arranged like this:

$\hspace{50pt}$[image: four cubes]

Observe, that two red and two blue edges form a [parallelogram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogram), but it is symmetric
(find the appropriate symmetry yourself) and as such it is a rectangle, hence, the angle between red and blue edge is $90^\circ$.

I hope this helps ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If we assume the cube has unit side length and lies in the first octant with faces parallel to the coordinate planes and one vertex at the origin, then the the vector $(1,1,0)$ describes a diagonal of a face, and the vector $(1,1,1)$ describes the skew diagonal.

The angle between two vectors $u$ and $v$ is given by:

$$\cos(\theta)=\frac{u\cdot v}{|u||v|}$$

In our case, we have

$$\cos(\theta)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{6}}\quad\Longrightarrow\quad\theta\approx 35.26$$

Answer (score 0):

the answer will be 90 one vector is (1,1,1) and other is (1,0,-1)

Comment: Welcome to Maths.SE, and thank you for your answer! It is much more likely that it will be useful for others if you include some explanation for your assertions -- I suggest you [edit] your answer to do so.